# Disable "Sold Out" email in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I'm currently setting up a shopping site using WordPress and WooCommerce.

I'd like to disable the "Sold Out" email received when a product runs out of inventory after a successful purchase, since my client sees it as unnecessary.

However, I do not seem to find any documentation about where this email is defined or sent, does anyone know where I can get this information? Is it even possible to disable this email?

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like an appropriate question for the support forums of that product, or something you might find in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These can be disabled via the dashboard on the 'Inventory' section of the 'Products' tab. Accessible like so: `%%YOUR_SITE%%/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=products&section=inventory`